# Map array to an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, tsc

Say I have an array that looks like this:

```
const options =  [
 {
   name: 'foo',
   type: 'boolean'
 },

 {
   name: 'bar',
   type: 'string'
 },

 {
   name: 'bar', // should be baz not bar
   type: 'number'
 }

]
```

I am looking to use this array as an interface which would look something like this:

```
export interface Opts {
   foo: boolean,
   bar: string,
   baz: number
}
```

so that would probably have to be something like:

```
export type Opts = manipulate(typeof options);
```

where manipulate is some magical TS feature I hope to discover.

I believe this is a good place to start:
https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/01/20/typescript-2-1-mapped-types

but it's hard to figure out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but it requires both [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) types.

First you need a type that represents your mapping from type names like `"boolean"`, to actual types like `boolean`.

```
type TypeMapping = {
  boolean: boolean,
  string: string,
  number: number,
  // any other types
}
```

Then you need a helper function which makes sure your `options` value doesn't get its types for the `name` and `type` properties widened to `string`.  (If you inspect your `options` value, its type is something like `{name: string, type: string}[]`, which has lost track of the particular `name` and `type` values you want.)   You can use [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to do this, as follows:

```
const asOptions = <K extends keyof any, 
  T extends Array<{ name: K, type: keyof TypeMapping }>>(t: T) => t;
```

Let's see if it works:

```
const options = asOptions([
  {
    name: 'foo',
    type: 'boolean'
  },

  {
    name: 'bar',
    type: 'string'
  },

  {
    name: 'bar',
    type: 'number'
  }
]);
```

If you inspect that you will see that it is now an array of types where each of `name` and `type` are narrowed to the literals `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"number"`, etc.

Finally we have to do that `manipulate` type function you want.  I'll call it `OptionsToType`:

```
type OptionsToType<T extends Array<{ name: keyof any, type: keyof TypeMapping }>>
  = { [K in T[number]['name']]: TypeMapping[Extract<T[number], { name: K }>['type']] }
```

That might seem very complicated.  Let's see if I can break it down.

```
T extends Array<{ name: keyof any, type: keyof TypeMapping }>
```

means `T` must be an array of objects with a `name` field like an object key, and a `type` field like a key of the `TypeMapping` type above.

```
  = { [K in T[number]['name']]: ... }
```

iterate through all the key names in the `name` property from each element of the `T` array

```
  Extract<T[number], { name: K }>
```

means "find the element of `T` that corresponds to the name `K`"...

```
  Extract<T[number], { name: K }>['type']
```

...and look up its `'type'` property...

```
  TypeMapping[Extract<T[number], { name: K }>['type']]
```

...and use that as an index into the `TypeMapping` type.

Okay let's see if it works:

```
export type Opts = OptionsToType<typeof options>;
```

And if you inspect `Opts` you see:

```
{
    foo: boolean;
    bar: string | number;
}
```

just as you expected--- uh, wait, why is the `bar` property of type `string | number`?  Oh, because you put `bar` in `options` twice.  Change the second one to `baz` and it will be what you expect.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: holy cow, let me dive in

Comment: thanks for this - I am working on incorporating this answer - but I have a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174924/keyof-but-for-arraystring, basically it's the same as the OP here but name is an array like  `name: ['bar']` instead of  `name: 'bar'`