# Get type completion based on dynamic (mapped/conditional) type

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

You can drop the following code into a foo.ts file. I am trying to dynamically generate types. What I am doing is based off this question:
[Map array to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334324/map-array-to-an-interface)

```
type TypeMapping = {
  Boolean: boolean,
  String: string,
  Number: number,
  ArrayOfString: Array<string>,
}

export enum Type {
  Boolean = 'Boolean',
  String = 'String',
  Number = 'Number',
  ArrayOfString = 'ArrayOfString'
}

const asOptions = <K extends Array<string>, T extends Array<{ name: K, type: keyof TypeMapping }>>(t: T) => t;

type OptionsToType<T extends Array<{ name: Array<string>, type: keyof TypeMapping }>>
  = { [K in T[number]['name'][0]]: TypeMapping[Extract<T[number], { name: K }>['type']] }


const options = asOptions([
  {
    name: ['foo'],
    type: Type.Boolean
  },

  {
    name: ['bar'],
    type: Type.String
  },

  {
    name: ['baz'],
    type: Type.Number
  },

  {
    name: ['bab'],
    type: Type.ArrayOfString
  }
]);



export type Opts = OptionsToType<typeof options>;

const v = <Opts>{foo: true};  // this does not compile

console.log(typeof v.foo);
```

I don't get any type completion - when I type `v.` nothing shows up.

Comment: are you dead set on this interface? When I build these sorts of things objects (vs arrays) tend to be way easier because pre TS3 key iteration works. I'll put together an answer like this.

Comment: Why are you making the `name` property an array?  Your example only uses a single-element array (a "one-tuple")... if it's always just one element, why not use just a string instead?  If it's sometimes more than one element, can you show how you want it to be used?

Comment: It's for a user-convenience - they define an array of options, the first element is the name, the rest are aliases.

Comment: @AlexanderMills updated to not mess with your input shape too much, the trick with iterating a tuple is to exclude the keys on the Array<any> type. Note you'll have to make typescript infer your name strings correctly. It has a tendency to fight me when I do things like this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that uses Typescript 3, and an object as the input. I do something very similar to this in my own projects to generate a typed query builder wrapper for knex.js from my Postgres database.

```
// for lazier enum/mapping declaration
function StrEnum<T extends string[]>(...values: T) {
  let o = {};
  for (let v in values) {
    o[v] = v;
  }
  return o as { [K in T[number]]: K };
}
// declare enum values
const Type = StrEnum("Boolean", "String", "Number", "ArrayOfString");

// correlate the keys to things
type TypeMapping = {
  Boolean: boolean;
  String: string;
  Number: number;
  ArrayOfString: Array<string>;
};

// thing to convert your generated interface into something useful
const asOptions = <T extends { [key: string]: keyof TypeMapping }>(t: T) => t;

// the generated object
const options = asOptions({
  foo: Type.Boolean,
  bar: Type.String,
  baz: Type.Number,
  bab: Type.ArrayOfString
});

type Opts = Partial<
  { [V in keyof typeof options]: TypeMapping[typeof options[V]] }
>;

const v: Opts = { foo: true }; // this does compile

console.log(v);
```

Here is a way to use your current interface:

```
// for lazier enum/mapping declaration
function StrEnum<T extends string[]>(...values: T) {
  let o = {};
  for (let v in values) {
    o[v] = v;
  }
  return o as { [K in T[number]]: K };
}
// declare enum values
const Type = StrEnum("Boolean", "String", "Number", "ArrayOfString");

// correlate the keys to things
type TypeMapping = {
  Boolean: boolean;
  String: string;
  Number: number;
  ArrayOfString: Array<string>;
};

type OptDefinitionElement<K extends string, V extends keyof TypeMapping> = {
  name: K;
  value: V;
};

// thing to convert your generated interface into something useful
const asOptions = <T extends OptDefinitionElement<any, any>[]>(...t: T) => {
  return t;
};

// because typescript doesn't like to infer strings
// nested inside objects/arrays so precisely
function InferString<S extends string>(s: S) {
  return s;
}

// the generated object
const options = asOptions(
  { name: InferString("foo"), value: Type.Boolean },
  { name: InferString("bar"), value: Type.String },
  { name: InferString("baz"), value: Type.Number },
  { name: "bab" as "bab", value: Type.ArrayOfString } // note you don't *have* to use the Infer helper
);

// way to iterate keys and construct objects, and then result in the | type of all
// of the values
type Values<T extends { [ignoreme: string]: any }> = T extends {
  [ignoreme: string]: infer R;
}
  ? R
  : never;
type OptionsType = typeof options;
type OptionKeys = Exclude<keyof OptionsType, keyof Array<any>>;
type Opts = Values<
  {
    [TupleIndex in Exclude<keyof OptionsType, keyof Array<any>>]: {
      [key in OptionsType[TupleIndex]["name"]]: TypeMapping[OptionsType[TupleIndex]["value"]]
    }
  }
>;

const v: Opts = { foo: true }; // this does compile

console.log(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the first element of the `name` property as the actual key to add to the resultant type, your definitions are a little off.  I would fix them to be:

```
const asOptions = <
  K extends string, 
  T extends Array<{ name: {0: K}, type: keyof TypeMapping }>
>(t: T) => t;

type OptionsToType<T extends Array<{ name: Array<string>, type: keyof TypeMapping }>> = {
  [K in T[number]['name'][0]]: TypeMapping[Extract<T[number], { name: {0: K} }>['type']] 
}
```

The differences:

- I am still using `K extends string` to induce inference of a string literal in `asOptions`.  There are [places](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) where TypeScript infers string literals and other places where it infers just `string`, and `K extends Array<string>` will not infer a string literal.  So `K` is still a string type, and instead I've made the `name` property as `{0: K}` which will ensure that it inspects the first element of the array.
- Again in `OptionsToType`, `K` is a string literal, so you must extract the piece of `T['number']` that has `K` as the first element of the `name` property, which is `Extract<T[number], {name: {0: K} }>`.

The rest should work now, I think.  Hope that helps.  Good luck.